# Update Panel content when ListBox in other Panel changes

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, panel

I am new to GWT.

I have two `ListBox` elements (let's call them `A` and `B`) in two different panels (precisely `Composite` and `VerticalPanel` if that matters; let's call them `panelA` and `panelB`) which have a common parent (`parentPanel`).
**I want to update list of items in `A`, when `B` changes.**

**How do I do that in GWT?**
My first idea was to add `changeHandler` to `B` in which I call some public `updateItems()` method on `A`.
Hovewer, `panelA` is not accessible from `panelB` at all. Also to make things worse `A` is private inner class of `panelA`.

I can probably make all those classes/methods etc. public to get this working, but I feel this is not a right way.
Is my design bad? What is a proper way to do such things in GWT? I think I'm just missing a keyword to start research with...

Any help will be appreciated. Not asking for code, just a general concept or advice.

Comment: If the application design follows the MVP pattern you would have a presenter that controls the current view and has access to all components and thus can update its components.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll read about MVP and verify if it is used in the application I am working on, but this has to wait till tomorrow as I have no access to this code now.

Comment: Checked. This is a legacy code and MVP is not used at all. Any other solutions? GWT version we use is 2.40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Eventbus` you create an event

```
public class ListBoxBEvent extends GwtEvent<ListBoxBChanged.Handler> {

    public interface Handler extends EventHandler {
        void onListBoxBChanged(ListBoxBEvent listBoxBEvent);
    }

    public static final GwtEvent.Type<Handler> TYPE = new GwtEvent.Type<Handler>();
    private Object selectedObject;

    public VueChangedEvent(Object selectedObject) {
        this.selectedObject=selectedObject;
    }

    @Override
    public GwtEvent.Type<Handler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }
    @Override
    protected void dispatch(Handler handler) {
        handler.onListBoxBChanged(this);
    }

    public static HandlerRegistration register(EventBus eventBus, Handler handler) {
        return eventBus.addHandler(TYPE, handler);
    }

    public Object getSelectedObject(){
        return selectedObject;
    }

}
```

In the panelA which has the ListBoxA, you registrer to the event as follows

```
ListBoxBEvent.register(eventBus, new ListBoxBEvent.Handler() {
            @Override
            public void onListBoxBChanged (ListBoxBEvent listBoxBEvent) {
                Object seletetObject =  listBoxBEvent.getSelectedObject();
                updateListBoxB(seletetObject);
            }           
        });
```

In `OnChange` event of the `ListBoxB` you fire the `ListBoxBEvent`

```
view.getListBoxB().addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
       eventBus.fireEvent(new ListBoxBEvent(selectedObject));
    }
});
```

Make sure that you use one instance of EventBus object through the application by using a Singleton or DI

Comment: From what I've read, `EventBus` concept is also part of MVP architecture. Do you suggest implementing it even though I cannot use MVP?

Comment: I've ended up using this solution with little modifications. Really easy to add, even to legacy code.

Comment: Eventbus is not specific to MVP or to GWT and could be implemented alone (as you did).

Answer (score 1):

Use your Activity/Presenter to drive these changes. For example, in your Activity/Presenter:

```
myView.getListBoxB().addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        updateListBoxA();
    }
});

private void updateListBoxA() {
    ListBox listBoxA = myView.getListBoxA();
    // do what is necessary
}
```

You can also do it in your ParentPanel widget. It all depends on which design pattern you are following.

Comment: Thanks for an idea. Unfortunately, I cannot add ChangeHandler to `PanelB` as it is just a `VerticalPanel`. `PanelB` has inner class with property `B` of type `ListBox`. It's `B` that needs to have handler attached...

Answer (score 1):

As Moh mentioned it, you have to use  MVP archetecture see: [official documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html), presenter must have access to your A & B throw panelA and panelB, then bind your A. 
eg:

```
public class MyPresenter {
public interface Display {
 CheckBox getA();/* get button A to bind it to appropriate action */
 CheckBox getB(); /* get B to update it */
//.......other thing you want get from you View 
} // end of interface

private Display display;
/*
* you presenter logic ..
*/
//constructor and initialisation ...
public MyPresenter (Display display/*, MyService myService ..,.. refer to doc*/){
   this.diplay=display;
}

private void bind(){
   display.getA().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
@Override
public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {

     //access B by : then update it:: display.getB();
}
});
}//end bind().
// other staff ...
```

then you View must implements MyPresenter.Display interface.

```
public class MyView extends /*SomeClass*/ implements MyPresenter.Display{
/* view logic,  you must to refactor you code logic to be "more conform" to best practice
   see also the example in the doc  */
then you have to implement missing methods ( getA and getB ) ( or your widget) that make available you buttons to the presenter.
```

Comment: Unfortunately code I'm working on is huge and doesn't use MVP. Any other suggestions?